# WPF Ribbon Application Menu Button Color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF \ C# App with a ribbon.

I want to change the ribbon's main button's color.

`Ribbon Application Menu Button`

[image: Ribbon Application Menu Button]

Any ideas?

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="AccountantDatabase.Controls.BarRibbon"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AccountantDatabase.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Ribbon SelectedIndex="0" IsMinimized="True">
        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu KeyTip="A">
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Options"
                    Click="RibbonMenuItemOptions_Click"/>
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Exit"
                    Click="RibbonMenuItemExit_Click"/>
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <RibbonTab Header="Home" KeyTip="H">
        </RibbonTab>
        <RibbonTab Header="Filter" KeyTip="F">
        </RibbonTab>
    </Ribbon>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Please, add your xaml code so we can help you

Comment: Open up the project in Blend and modify the style which sets the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
<Ribbon>
     <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
         <RibbonApplicationMenu Background="Red" BorderBrush="Red">
             <!-- Content  -->
         </RibbonApplicationMenu>
     </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>          
 </Ribbon>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Template for Ribbon: [Link](https://gist.github.com/drayde/75526b570a266f5f8f38)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Shubham.